# Can Outlook 2007 tell me which encoding an email is in?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, encoding

I'm having an issue (in a different application) with an email supposedly in UTF-7 encoding. If I have received that email in my Outlook 2007 inbox, can Outlook confirm the encoding of the email?

This [link suggests it should be under Actions -> Other Actions](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=7741) but all I have under there is  'Forward as Attachment'

Is this because it is an automated Undeliverable email?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the message header (Open the email and then look at the message Properties) it should give you a bit more information on how it was encoded there. Something like:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Comment: Thanks - how do I look at the message Properties? I'm not sure if my Outlook has been particularly locked down by our IT departments, but I don't see a way to get them.

Comment: Ah, it looks that in 2007 you right-click on the email and click Message Options. Look at this: http://youtu.be/WBrq_9Yw6fc

Comment: For me I had to open the email, then click on the File tab, then click on the "Properties" button. Thanks for you help.